# Dojo1.8: _WidgetBase does not sound good to me

Tags: dojo

Hi It seems that using _WidgetBase is is a bad idea to use.
What I was looking for is that I can make instances (with different properties from the class button).

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom","dojo/dom_construct", "dijit/_WidgetBase", dojo/domReady!],
    function(declare, dom, domConstruct, _WidgetBase)
     {
      ready(function()
      {
        declare("myBtn", [_WidgetBase],
          {buildRendering: function()
    {
             this.domNode = domConstruct.create('button');
    }
      });

        registry.byId(new myBtn(
          {id:'btn1',
           label:'HelloA'                            
      }).placeAt(dom.byId('line1')));

        registry.byId(new myBtn(
          {id:'btn2',
           label:'HelloB'                            
      }).placeAt(dom.byId('line2')));

        registry.byId(new myBtn(
          {id:'btn3',
           label:'HelloC'                            
      }).placeAt(dom.byId('line3')));

      }
     });
```

So I am wondering if it is okay to use _WidgetBase, when I wanted to add different properties for each button?

Comment: Please see my work in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/E73mp/25/

Comment: As Erikas pointed out, why are you trying to create a button widget when dijit/form/Button is already there ? Also, what's the point of using registry.byId the way you are using it ?

Comment: Why not inherit from `dijit/form/Button` (instead of _WidgetBase). You can override the functions you need to, add your own, completely customize it to your needs. As Erikas mentioned, there is nothing wrong with inheriting from _WidgetBase, but that only gives you a Dijit widget skeleton.

Comment: In that case, how many are there ways to create class, create instances from the class with inheritances of properties and functions that can be modified? 1) dojo/_base/declare 2)extend_WidgetBase. so there are two ways to do same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your issue, while you can just use dijit/form/button (http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/form/Button). If the button is just an example and you still need to extend _WidgetBase - answer to your question is yes, it is ok to use it, but there's a bit more code to write to make it configurable and flexible.